# ios voip app run only 10 min in background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, voip

I am creating a voip application for iPhone and iPad family in which I have done following things :

1. Added the **UIBackgroundModes** key in the plist file with values '**audio**' and '**voip**'.
2. Create **NSInputStream** and **NSOutputStream** with tag **NSStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP** and scheduled them in runloop of another thread(not main thread).
3. Created a background task in **applicationDidEnterBackground**.
4. Added **setKeepAliveTimeout**  handler (timeout value 600 sec).

Application relaunches when code in handler of **setKeepAliveTimeout** is called.

Application relaunches if I dont put setKeepAliveTimeout handler ,but tries to send any signal to app after suspension(10 mins in background is completed).

I have tried almost everything that came in my mind, Need pointers towards the solution Thanks in advance,

Comment: I am going with the same problem since 4 weeks, No solution found till now. How did you solve it? can you help me please. I have posted many question about this http://stackoverflow.com/q/19273039/2459296 http://stackoverflow.com/q/19288356/2459296 http://stackoverflow.com/q/19762071/2459296 http://stackoverflow.com/q/19807074/2459296

Answer (score 1):

It is the duty of the setKeepAliveTimeout handler to care about the connection. Thus, you should use an alive interval that is shorter than the timeout time of your connection.