# iOS - UILocalNotification on SIP call

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, notifications

I have a VoIP application. All is going fine with this application.

When application is in foreground for incoming call I am getting a SIP notification and showing Calling dialog.

**But the problem is:**

When my app is in background and for incoming call I am getting SIP notification.

How to prompt it to user.

Please help me.

Comment: The answer is in your title, [`UILocalNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: To show UILocalNotification when app is in background I have need to start a Background Task. But after 10 mins. it dose not work.

Comment: You should register you as a voip app to keep it running in the background. Read Apple [Tips for Developing a VoIP App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW12)

Comment: It's backgroundmode has set to voip already. so application is live in background and incoming call is working fine. just problem is I couldn't show UILocalNotification after going to background after 10 mins. for Background task within 10 mins Notification working. after finishing background task it is not working.

Comment: Seems to me like you are not really running in the background. Since the 10 min. background task rule only applies to app that are not in the VoIP, music, location or accessory background running category. Make sure your is keeping a VoIP socket alive and that you entered the correct background mode.

Comment: App is running. cause after > 10 mins if a call comes UILocalNotification not appeares to user but if app opens at this time calling dialog appear to user to receive call.

Comment: Problem is without background task notification does not appeare to user. BackTask finish after 10 mins.

Comment: You do not need background tasks for a VoIP client, you need to set the background mode to voip.